# How to convert color opencv image to scikit without saving to disk?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I have color image loaded with imread, I need to convert it to scikit-compatible image. Currently I do it like this:

```
            cv2.imwrite("./tmp/prt.png",prt)
            imm = Image.open("./tmp/prt.png")
```

how can I do this without temporary file?

Comment: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html#working-with-opencv

Comment: this guide is missleading, img_as_float doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, could you be more specific?  If the guide is incorrect we'd like to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

`cv2.imread` loads an image from a file and returns a NumPy array. From the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#cv2.imread):

> **Note:** In the case of color images, the decoded images will have the channels stored in B G R order.

In `skimage` the colour channels are stored in R G B order though. Therefore, all you need to do to achieve compatibility between OpenCV and scikit-image is swapping the read and green channels like this:

```
imm = prt[:, :, ::-1]
```